# Order arrays by price within an array after foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have created an array of arrays (I think) during a foreach loop:

```
$collectGroup = array();
foreach ($topTenList->searchResult->item as $group) {
    $collectGroup['title'] = $group->title;
    $collectGroup['price'] = $group->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice;
    $collectGroup['image'] = $group->galleryURL;
    $collectGroup['url']   = $group->viewItemURL;
}
```

Var dumping the array outputs:

```
array(4) {
  ["title"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(74) "title 1"
  }
  ["price"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["currencyId"]=>
      string(3) "GBP"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(9) "1500000.0"
  }
  ["image"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "http://www.website.com/image1.jpg"
  }
  ["url"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(140) "http://www.website.com"
  }
}

array(4) {
  ["title"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(80) "title 2"
  }
  ["price"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["currencyId"]=>
      string(3) "GBP"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(9) "8000088.0"
  }
  ["image"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "http://www.website.com/image2.jpg"
  }
  ["url"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(140) "http://www.website.com"
  }
}
```

What I would now like to do is order the arrays within the array by price descending. SO in this instance it should have the array with a price of 8000088.0 above the array with a price of 1500000.0.
I have tried:

```
ksort($collectGroup['price'], SORT_NUMERIC);
```

But no luck, any help please

Comment: You need to convert your simplexml objects... Price is a string... But should be float.

Comment: like so?

$collectGroup['price'] = number_format((float)$group->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice, 2, '.', ',');

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($collectGroup, function ($first, $second) {
  return $second['price'] - $first['price'];
});
```

Read the documentation on usort and you'll see how this works.

Comment: I can't get it to work how I want, it has moved the price element to beginning of each array eg

[0]price [1]url [2]image [3]title

But not ordered each array in order of price..

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I can see you have created an array of `SimpleXMLElement` Objects, not multidimensional array. To get a multidimensional array you should do something like this:

```
        $collectGroup = array();
        foreach ($topTenList->searchResult->item as $group) {
            $collectGroup['title'] = $group->title[0];
            $collectGroup['price'] = $group->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice[0];
            $collectGroup['image'] = $group->galleryURL[0];
            $collectGroup['url']   = $group->viewItemURL[0];
        }
```

And you have yourself an multidimensional array. Sorry If I am wrong about the array access in the `SimpleXMLElement`, but don't use it often, I prefer JSON. Anyways @aaaaaa123456789 (Nice name :) ) shows you a good approach.

Comment: Meh, I couldn't think of a better name when I had to make an account for some site in like 10 seconds :P (And I liked the name, so I kept it for everything else.)